# My computer shuts down when I try to run windows 10 on virtual-box.-mac

Tags: virtualbox

When I open windows 10 on virtual-box, it starts to load and then it just freezes, and then my computer shuts down. Do you have any idea on how I can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Does the VirtualBox log contain any helpful relevant information?

Answer (score 1):

You may have too much RAM allocated for the VM. If your machine doesn't have that much RAM or a good enough CPU it may be difficult or impossible for your machine to run a stable VM depending on what OS you are trying to run.